# Replicate, Repeat or other?

Tags: r

I have the code as detailed below. The basic description of what I require is to repeat this code 30 times and have the end values assigned as a vector if possible. I also need the seed to be increased by one each time the simulation is run. So I was thinking about using replicate or maybe repeat. But as replicate needs `rep(vector, times)`, I'm not so sure as I don't have a specific vector to be assigned.

To explain the code a little better, A is a first best guess of values which in turn informs B. B is then used as input to C which informs D. C and D then iterate until convergence for three values.

```
rep(vector,40){
set.seed(100)

...............
A
..............
B
..............

for (n in 1:50){
...............
C
..............
D
..............
}
}
```

Comment: replicate takes an expression, not a vector.  Take a closer look as it's likely what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just wrap everything in a function and then use sapply to feed an index into your function.

```
yourfun <- function(seed){
    set.seed(seed)
    # your code here

    ans <- rnorm(1)
    # just so we can return something
    return(ans)
}

sapply(seq(500, 530), yourfun)
```

Comment: Hi, yes i ran this with my code and it seems to work. Just one issue, when i run my code once, i get four values for specific parameters. When i use the above method, it still completes but i see 30 values which are nonsense. I try to call the parameter (e.g. yourfun["o1"] with no luck), any ideas?

Comment: i have obviously assigned what i want to be returned but because its from an optimisation routine, im getting par, value, count, convergence and message values for each of the 30. The numeric values are what i want but trying to them in any way (eg yourfun["o$par"]) results in the following: Error in test1["o$par"] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Just modify what is returned from yourfun.  Or you could use lapply to get the entire result from optim and then later you could use lapply to grab only the pieces you want.